# Undefined method 'news' in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in my rails news controller, and when i insert the code, @user.news.build in my def new method it runs ok in the console, but in my localhost in runs this error,

```
undefined method `news' for nil:NilClass

  def new
    @news = current_user.news.build
  end
```

Why won't it run in the site and but run in the console?

Comment: Your `current_user` is not set. Are you sure user is logged in?

Comment: Oh thanks Vimsha :-), i can accept the answer if you post it as one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_user` is nil

`current_user` will be set to the session user once the user logs in. Make sure that the user is logged in